# Error in Angular service/factory method assigning the same integer values to different dates in a loop

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angular-services

I have an error in my Angular service/factory method `(createArray(dateArray, valueArray))` that **assigns the same integer values (in a loop) to different dates**.

**This service/factory method takes 2 arrays of values** as parameters, and is supposed to create an **array of arrays** `[[{},{}],[{},{}]]` consisting of objects with a **Date** and a **Value**, grouped by ISO weeks.

The first part of the service/factory seems to work as expected. Firstly, it takes the array of dates, and with the help of helper methods, creates the array of arrays of weeks.

**Example:**

```
Create Week Array (Part 1): [
   [
      "2016-11-01",
      "2016-11-02",
      "2016-11-03",
      "2016-11-04",
      "2016-11-05",
      "2016-11-06"
   ],
   [
      "2016-11-07",
      "2016-11-08",
      "2016-11-09",
      "2016-11-10",
      "2016-11-11",
      "2016-11-12",
      "2016-11-13"
   ],
```

The second part of the method is supposed to take the second parameter passed to it - the array of integer values - and assign a value to each date in order.

**This is where the error is, as the same integer values are getting repeated for each array of week days.**

**Example:**

```
Create Week Array (End Part 2): [
   [
      {
         "2016-11-01": 319
      },
      {
         "2016-11-02": 782
      },
      {
         "2016-11-03": 579
      },
      {
         "2016-11-04": 642
      },
      {
         "2016-11-05": 444
      },
      {
         "2016-11-06": 274
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "2016-11-07": 319
      },
      {
         "2016-11-08": 782
      },
      {
         "2016-11-09": 579
      },
      {
         "2016-11-10": 642
      },
      {
         "2016-11-11": 444
      },
      {
         "2016-11-12": 274
      },
      {
         "2016-11-13": 481
      }
   ],
```

**Here is an example of the array of integers passed to the method:**

```
"time_trend": [319,782,579,642,444,274,481,738,558,663,387,197,185,461,464,681,549,342,432,295,656,502,1266,1272,1109,724,440,1019,1056,1037,764]
```

**Here is an example of the array of dates passed to the method:**

```
"timeline_data": ["2016-11-01","2016-11-02","2016-11-03","2016-11-04","2016-11-05","2016-11-06","2016-11-07","2016-11-08","2016-11-09","2016-11-10","2016-11-11","2016-11-12","2016-11-13","2016-11-14","2016-11-15","2016-11-16","2016-11-17","2016-11-18","2016-11-19","2016-11-20","2016-11-21","2016-11-22","2016-11-23"]
```

**Here is my service/factory method and helper methods:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('portalDashboardApp')
        .factory('GroupDateRangeService', GroupDateRangeService);

    GroupDateRangeService.$inject = [];

    function GroupDateRangeService() {

        var service = {
            createArray: createArray,
            assignWeekNamesAndTotals: assignWeekNamesAndTotals,
            setSeries: setSeries,
            createMonthlyArray: createMonthlyArray,
            assignMonthNamesAndTotals: assignMonthNamesAndTotals,
            setSeriesByMonth: setSeriesByMonth
        };

        return service;

        function createArray(dateArray, valueArray) {

            // PART 1
            var arr = dateArray.map(function (s) {
                var week = getWeekNumber(parseISOLocal(s));
                return week[0] + ('0' + week[1]).slice(-2) + ':' + s;
            }).sort();

            console.log("Create Week Array (Step 0.5): " + JSON.stringify(arr, null, "   "));

            var results = createGroupedArray(createGroupObject(arr));
            console.log("Create Week Array (Part 1): " + JSON.stringify(results, null, "   "));

            // PART 2
            if (valueArray && valueArray.length === dateArray.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    results[i] = results[i].map(function (date, index) {
                        var obj = {};
                        obj[date] = valueArray[index];

                        return obj;
                    });
                }
            }
            console.log("Create Week Array (End Part 2): " + JSON.stringify(results, null, "   "));
            return results;
        }

/////HELPERS/////

        function createGroupObject(arr) {
            var groupedObj = arr.reduce(function (result, value) {
                var b = value.split(':');
                if (!result[b[0]]) result[b[0]] = [];
                result[b[0]].push(b[1]);
                return result;
            }, {});
            console.log("Grouped Object: " + groupedObj);
            return groupedObj;           
        }

        function createGroupedArray(groupedObj) {
            // Grab arrays in order of week number. Sort keys to maintain order
            //var groupedArray = Object.keys(groupedObj).sort().map(key=>groupedObj[key]); ECMA2015
            var groupedArray = Object.keys(groupedObj).sort()
                .map(function (key) {
                    return groupedObj[key];
                });

            console.log("Grouped Array: " + groupedArray);
            return groupedArray;          
        }

        /* Helper to get the ISO week number of a date
        ** @param {Date} date to get week of
        ** @returns {Array} [year, weekNumber]
        */
        function getWeekNumber(d) {
            d = new Date(+d);
            d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
            var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            var weekNo = Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
            return [d.getFullYear(), weekNo];
        }

        // Returns [year, monthNumber]
        function getMonthNumber(d) {
            d = new Date(+d);
            d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            var monthNo = d.getMonth()
            return [d.getFullYear(), monthNo];
        }

        /* Parse ISO 8601 format date string to local date
        ** @param {string} s - string to parse like 2016-12-15
        ** @returns {Date}
        */
        function parseISOLocal(s) {
            var b = s.split(/\D/); // Removes dashes (-) from date. Example: 2017-01-09 to 2017,01,09
            var newDate = new Date(b[0], b[1] - 1, b[2]); // Creates a new Local date from the date sting/parameters 
            return newDate;
        }
    }

})();
```

I would appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is happening because of this statement:

```
results[i] = results[i].map(function (date, index) {
...
obj[date] = valueArray[index];
```

You're iterating over array of arrays. And each time you iterate over an inner array the index becomes 0 due to which it keeps repeating the same set of values. Try to use replace the above code with this:

```
var counter=0;
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
results[i] = results[i].map(function (date) {
...
obj[date] = valueArray[counter++];
```

Comment: Ouch! Thank you, much appreciated :D

Comment: any other way for some repeated value max 5 times then create new array and remove that value from array? I HAVE THIS KIND OF ARRAY: ["info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition"]